# Connect multiple Charts

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to do something like this with ChartJs?
[image]

I've already figured out, how to make a custom tooltip and also this vertical follow line.
But, how can I do this, that multiple Charts show their value at the index.

### **EDIT**

I've already tried to use a stacked chart, but that's not what I want, cause some values are the same, like the percentage of the gas and brake pedal, but the values should be separated like this.
I've also tried to use a parent chart and somehow to simulate a mouse hover on the other charts, but that didn't work.

Note: The software is called "SimRacingTelemetry". If you want to take a closer look.